# Receiving the client side data into binary or byte or binary64

Tags: database, binary, wso2, wso2-esb

My client sending the data as  image or video i am going to receive the this data  binary or byte or binary64 in WSo2 ESB Proxy service.

help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [MTOM/SWA](http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26838822) samples in ESB

Comment: Thanks for Replay,is it support for streaming.If connection failed in the middle of the video,after that it could be resume from last stream.How could be achieved from WSO2 ESB.